# UITextField placeholder sizeToFit

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit

I have a `UITextField` in a view.
That textfield has a `placeholder`.

Whenever I invoke the `[UITextField sizeToFit]` on the text field the width always seems to be less than the actual value. I am getting the placeholder with clipped at the end.

is there a way to "size" a text field with a placeholder that does not mess the placeholder representation.

Comment: It says on the documentation "Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews." Isn't the placeholder a subview of the text field? After setting a placeholder text and an empty text, and calling sizeToFit I thought that It would resize the textfield to fit all it's subviews, including the placeholder one.

Comment: Then why does it work when I set the `text` property to some string and call the `sizeToFit` method? I am not meaning to waste your time, but this isn't clear to me, and I want to understand it. Basically if I set `text = @"Search"` and call `sizeToFit` it the view resizes as I expected. If I set `placeholder = @"Search"` my view returns a shorter width that doesn't fit the whole "Search" word. This is what isn't clear to me.